# What is the proper way to write a code block in a go function comment?

Tags: go, documentation

I want to include some example codes in my comment for a function, like this:

````golang
// Some example for using `foo`:
//
// ```
//   f := Foo(...)
//   g := Goo(f)
// ```
func Foo() {
  ...
}
````

But the code block is not displayed properly in vscode. What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Backticks have no effect with the standard godoc, and code-blocks are written by indentation.

Comment: Also consider writing a [real executable example](https://blog.golang.org/examples).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove those backticks and just indent the code:

```
// Foo does ... (note this first line)
// Some example for using Foo:
//
//   f := Foo(...)
//   g := Goo(f)
func Foo() {
  ...
}
```

Quoting from [The Go Blog: Godoc: documenting Go code:](https://blog.golang.org/godoc)

> There are a few formatting rules that Godoc uses when converting comments to HTML:
>
> - Subsequent lines of text are considered part of the same paragraph; you must leave a blank line to separate paragraphs.
> - **Pre-formatted text must be indented relative to the surrounding comment text (see gob's doc.go for an example).**
> - URLs will be converted to HTML links; no special markup is necessary.

Related questions:

[Godoc documentation not outputting lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52744468/godoc-documentation-not-outputting-lists/52745058#52745058)

[GoDoc add newline character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641640/godoc-add-newline-character/51641739#51641739)

[What are Go example functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141579/what-are-go-example-functions/29141725#29141725)